# How to propagate linux kernel driver patches between linux versions

Tags: git, synchronization, fetch, repository

Consider this scenario of maintaining a kernel space driver for 2 linux versions (say 3.1 and 3.4)
A bug fix on linux version 3.1 involving many files is also applicable to ver 3.4.
Now my question is how to propagate these fixes from ver 3.1 to 3.4 ?
From what I understand the kernel is a monolithic GIT repository and it is not possible to Git fetch the fix from 3.1 to 3.4.
Is there a better way of doing this other than merging the fixes manually ?

Best regards,
Ganesh.